# What sourcebook is Improved Reallocation (Changeling Feat) from?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, chameleon

### What sourcebook is the feat Improved Reallocation from?

In an effort to stay with officially published material as per my DM's table rules - I would like to know if the above mentioned feat is real - and where it is from.

Source: https://eberron-hok.obsidianportal.com/wikis/improved-reallocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked my 3.5e books and found nothing. It looks to be from [this Pathfinder homebrew](https://bg-archive.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=11958), dated May 2011 (two years older than your link).

Comment: On following the link, there's a reasonably well made wiki, including the [Improved Reallocation](http://pf-eberron.wikidot.com/feats:improved-reallocation) feat.